# How to set a favicon to text

Tags: html, image, favicon

I know it is possible to set a favicon from an image like so:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Is there a way to set it as text instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode a Data URI of an SVG that contains a text element ([source](https://github.com/sindresorhus/sindresorhus.github.com/blob/f3520a62df7570b57717371b2b7611d5fd5256e4/_layouts/default.html#L31)):

```html
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 100 100%22><text y=%22.9em%22 font-size=%2290%22></text></svg>">
```